# Python : Why does zip land me a "SyntaxError: can't assign to function call"

Tags: python

In my code I zip together two lists of dicts, one defined simply (amud_titles) and one with a method (amud_ranges).

When I try to iterate like this:

```
for zip(amud, amud_range) in zip(amud_titles,get_amud_index()):
```

I get this error:

```
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call
```

Yet when I iterate like this:

```
for amud_range in get_amud_index():
```

I don't get any errors.

The method which generates the second list is pretty complicated, but I assume that's not the problem since I only have issues when I start using zip...

Answer (score 1):

You're using incorrect syntax for a for-loop.

When you want to loop through something, the syntax is:

```
for x in y
```

Where x is the variable assigned to each item of y, where y is an iterative object (list, etc). If you have a list with multiple objects per iteration (eg, a list returned by `zip()`, then you can assign multiple variables to multiple objects.

```
lst = [("a", "b"), ("c", "d")]
for i in lst:
    print(i) # Prints ("a", "b") then ("c", "d")

for i, j in lst:
    print(i)
    print(j) # Prints "a" then "b" then "c" then "d"
```

---

So in your example, `for zip(amud, amud_range) in zip(amud_titles,get_amud_index()):`, you don't actually need that first `zip()` around those variable names. Python is expecting variable names, not any structure of some sort.

Just do `for amud, amud_range in zip(amud_titles,get_amud_index()):`